# Can Qt lrelease tool process XLIFF files instead of ts-files?

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

In the documentation of the [Qt lrelease tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-manager.html) I read, that `.ts` files can be compiled to `.qm` binaries using following command:

```
lrelease.exe main_en.ts languages\main_fr.ts
```

Is it possible to take `.xliff` files as well as input instead of the `.ts` files to compile `.xliff` files to `.qm` files? How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of lupdate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-manager.html#using-lupdate), it is mentioned that you can generate `.ts` file from `XLIFF` files. You can then use `lrelease` to generate the `.qm` file.

Be aware that only the XLIFF 1.1 format is supported, not the 1.0.

Comment: Yes I saw it as well but it doesn't give me a `.ts` file when I call it with a `.xlf` file like following `lupdate E:\Users\<User>\Desktop\<.xlf file>` or `lupdate -ts E:\Users\<User>\Desktop\<.xlf file>` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `xlf` file to make some tests ?

Comment: Better check the results though, I’ve had translators use xliff, and the conversion from ts to xliff and back had issues, paragraphs got lost, due to nested elements that linguist’s converter didn’t understand. (don’t have the files around anymore to check the version)

Comment: @Frodon I think I can provide an `.xlf` file later
@FrankOsterfeld so the lupdate doesnt convert between these file types properly?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Can you give me an example how to call lupdate to convert from xliff to .ts??

Comment: @MarcelMüller I did that from within the Qt Linguist UI

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thank you for your advises I could resolve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

To convert a xliff file to ts, you can use the `lconvert` utility with a command line like this:

```
lconvert -o converted.ts -i original.xlf
```

Here is the output of `lconvert -help`:

> Usage:
>       lconvert [options]  [...]
>
> lconvert is part of Qt's Linguist tool chain. It can be used as a
>   stand-alone tool to convert and filter translation data files. The
>   following file formats are supported:
>
> ```
> qm    - Compiled Qt translations
> pot   - GNU Gettext localization template files
> ts11  - Qt translation sources (format 1.1)
> ts20  - Qt translation sources (format 2.0)
> qph   - Qt Linguist 'Phrase Book'
> ts    - Qt translation sources (latest format)
> po    - GNU Gettext localization files
> xlf   - XLIFF localization files
> ```
>
> If multiple input files are specified, they are merged with
>   translations from later files taking precedence.
>
> Options:
>       -h
>       --help  Display this information and exit.
>
> ```
> -i <infile>
> --input-file <infile>
>        Specify input file. Use if <infile> might start with a dash.
>        This option can be used several times to merge inputs.
>        May be '-' (standard input) for use in a pipe.
>
> -o <outfile>
> --output-file <outfile>
> ```

More info  [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Localization) about this Qt tool